# Is it okay to remove the roof gutter when installing patio cover connected to the roof fascia?

Tags: roof, patio, gutters

I want to install an insulated patio roof over a balcony by connecting it to the house roof fascia. The patio roof panels are too thick to fit under the house roof gutter. Is it okay to remove the gutter and let the water from the main roof run over to the patio roof? Will I need to do anything specific to prevent any future problem? The house roof is covered by concrete tiles and the house frame, roof trusses, and fascia are all made of timber. The new patio roof is insulated metal.

Comment: Answers depend on the details of the interface between the roofs. I'm not comfortable answering with so little information.

Comment: I might be concerned on how the new roof would be sealed to prevent rain from blowing back and dripping inside.

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to me to remove the gutters from the main roof, allow the rain to fall onto the patio roof, then (re)install guttering on the patio roof to direct the water away, most likely to wherever the original guttering sent it.

Letting the water just spill over the edge of the patio roof is asking for erosion of the ground around the patio, eventually allowing the patio to be flooded, and potentially causing foundation damage/basement flooding to the main house itself.